# string.Contains(string) error in Metro App

Tags: c#

I'm facing with some errors on the following codes shown below. It is reading from a .txt file which contains "A,B,D,E" in it. I'm using these letters to represent each characters for my game. I can't seem to solve this errors :/

I'm actually using Metro App on Visual Studio 2012, c#

Codes:

```
                var l = 0;
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();

                    for (var c = 0; c < line.Length; c++)
                    {
                        mazeValues[c, l] = line[c];

                        if ("ABDE".Contains(mazeValues[c, l])) // Error showing here
                        {
                            var index = "ABDE".IndexOf(mazeValues[c, l]);

                            ghosts[index].OriginalCellPoint = new Point(c, l);
                        }
                    }
                    l++;
                }
            }
```

Error showing:
The best overloaded match for 'string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: what is `mazeValues[c, l]`?

Comment: @JW웃 char[,] mazeValues = new char[mazeWidth, mazeHeight];

Comment: looks like it expects a string as it states - line is a string but your doing line[c]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `mazeValus[c, l]` is a character, and not a string.

Try `"ABDE".Contains(mazeValues[c, l].ToString())`

Comment: You could also try `IndexOf` and not call `ToString`

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see an overload for `IndexOf` that accepts a character argument .... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

Comment: @fafarifah oh, I see, I forgot about that. No problem then!

Comment: @fafarifah voting up is different from accepting an answer. When you cast a vote, you need to click the `UP` and `DOWN` arrow while you you accept an answer, you need to click the *white* checkmark below the votes to make it green `:)`.

Comment: @JW웃 Oh i see.. Hahah! Thank you, I'm still quite new at this(: